# Como remover dinamicamente todos os acentos agudos contidos em uma String?

Tags: dart

Como remover dinamicamente todos os acentos agudos contidos em uma String?

Exemplo:  “sofá sintético sólido”.

```
void funcao(String texto) {
  var resultado = '';
  for (var i = texto.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    resultado += texto[i];
  }
  print(resultado);
}

void main() {
  funcao('Olá mundo');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void main() {
  String s = "Eaí? Como vai você?";
  print(removerAcentos(s));
}

String removerAcentos(String str) {

  var comAcento = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
  var semAcento = 'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz'; 

  for (int i = 0; i < comAcento.length; i++) {      
    str = str.replaceAll(comAcento[i], semAcento[i]);
  }

  return str;
}
```

> Pode existir outras formas de tratar as acentuações (Talvez até melhores), mas essa é uma delas.

**Explicação**

O método *removerAcentos* irá percorrer cada caractere existente na variável *comAcento* e trocar todas as ocorrências, dentro do texto informado, desse caractere pelo caractere na mesma posição que esta na variável *semAcento*.

Answer (score 0):

O método normalize() retorna a Forma de Normalização Unicode (Unicode Normalization Form) de uma dada string. [Método normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

```js
var string = "sofá sintético sólido";
var string_norm = string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
console.log(string_norm);


var string2 = "O método normalize() retorna a Forma de Normalização Unicode (Unicode Normalization Form) de uma dada string";
var string_norm2 = string2.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
console.log(string_norm2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra usar o package [diacritic](https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic).

A função

```
removeDiacritics(suaString)
```

Vai retornar uma string com todos os acentos substituídos pela letra correspondente. Exemplo: 'á' vira 'a', 'ç' vira 'c'.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).